# how to convert string 'Mon Mar 14 05:21:08 UTC 2022" into datetime python

Tags: python, datetime

this is working

```
datetime.strptime('2012-03-01T10:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

same need to do for

```
datetime.strptime('Mon Mar 14 05:21:08 UTC 2022', '<format>')
```

what would be format for same

Comment: You can find the list of codes [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the parser in dateutil.

```
from dateutil import parser
my_date = parser.parse('Mon Mar 14 05:21:08 UTC 2022')
print(my_date) # datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 5, 21, 8, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to explicitly provide the corresponding [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for that timestamp

```
>>> datetime.strptime('Mon Mar 14 05:21:08 UTC 2022', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 5, 21, 8)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that %Z *accepts* "UTC" but doesn't do anything with it - so resulting datetime object is naive and thus represents local time